# use -v to see invocation doesn't seem to work in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, linker-errors, ld

I'm getting an error when building a C++ program in Xcode:
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Adding -v to "other linker flags" is not giving me more information.  I've cleaned and rebuilt.  I've also tried passing -v to clang just in case.

I inherited a .cpp with a .hpp that has a ton of includes so need to be able to find which header is including the offending method. Not sure how I would easily find the offending method without more information from the linker.

Ideas on the best approach to finding duplicate symbols as well as resolving this issue with -v not working?

I've also tried passing --verbose.

Comment: If you look slightly above that line in the output, it says "duplicate symbol 'the symbol name' in [...]". The exact invocation will tell you very little.

Comment: No it tells which files the duplicates are occurring in but it doesn't tell me anything about what .hpp or .h it is getting included from.  There are lots of .h files getting included from a 3rd party SDK so it would be very time consuming to try to eliminate possibilities one at a time and rebuild each time.  Also I may need to do this again so want to know why the -v isn't working.

Comment: @molbdnilo I know what the problem is, I just don't know an easy quick way to locate the offending in a long list of #includes that are from a 3rd party SDK.  I inherited the code and now need to clean it up so I can use the class with the problematic .hpp from other .cpps.

Comment: The linker invocation will tell you nothing about where the symbol originates from. If you have the name, can't you search for it?

Comment: @molbdnilo I can but it isn't convenient.  I guess I will have to resort to going to the location of the SDK in terminal and running grep -r <offending name>.  Not the most efficient process especially if there are more than 1.